# How to get hours in moment.js in GMT timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

For example if I do for the above date object something like: `value.hours()`, I get as output `16` instead of `18`. I believe it returns the hours in the original GMT time, not like in my date object which is GMT+2. I can of course add 2 to the returned result, but it becomes cumbersome. Is there any way to get the hours correctly in my case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as to what you've already tried, but I put the following into JSFiddle and it worked like a charm. I am currently in CST in America and it is 8:30 in the morning here. When I ran the snippet below I got today's date at 1:30 PM which I would assume is accurate in difference.

***HTML***

```
<div id="m1"></div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
var a = moment.tz(new Date(), "GMT");
document.getElementById('m1').innerHTML = a.format("YYYY MM DD; HH:mm");
```

The [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) documentation states the following in regards to creating a `Moment` object with a native JavaScript `Date` object:

> You can create a `Moment` with a pre-existing native JavaScript `Date` object.

```
var day = new Date(2011, 9, 16);
var dayWrapper = moment(day);
```

> This clones the `Date` object; further changes to the `Date` won't affect the `Moment`, and vice-versa.

To find the information quoted above quickly, when you reach the Moment.js documentation, it is located under the ***Parse*** section under sub-section ***Date***.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can solve it by doing what the docs says. Something like this:

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/

Answer (score 0):

To display local time:

```
value.local();
value.hours(); // 18
```

To reverse:

```
value.utc();
value.hours(); // 16
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe this works

```
var localDateString = new Date("GMT-DATETIME").toLocaleString(); 
//Converting GMT date to your local datetime in string


var localHours = new Date(localDateString).getHours();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).